# Find an English word having its pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation

I speak a persian language. I watch English video lessons about chess and I am not familiar with lots of the words and there are not any subtitles available. I wonder is there any way that I can recognize those unfamiliar words by their pronunciation? I try to guess the spelling of a word and search that, but sometimes it doesn't help.

Comment: If you guess the spelling reasonably closely Google will generally give suggestions.

Comment: You can also study lists of chess terms such as [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_chess) to become more familiar.